# Add server-side latitude/longitude values to Google Map javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-maps-api-2

I'm trying to add a Google map to one of my pages.

In my code-behind, I have a center point for the map, and an array of latitudes/longitudes that I'd like to map:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Point center = new Point { latitude = 28.42693F, longitude = -81.4673F };

    List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
    points.Add(new Point { latitude = 28.43039F, longitude = -81.47186F });
    points.Add(new Point { latitude = 28.36906F, longitude = -81.56063F });

    Point[] pointArray = points.ToArray();
}


public class Point
{
    public float latitude;
    public float longitude;
}
```

On my page, I have this javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function initialize() {
        if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
            var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
            map.setCenter(new GLatLng(28.42693, -81.4673), 13);
            //map.setUIToDefault();

            var blueIcon = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);
            blueIcon.image = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png";
            markerOptions = { icon: blueIcon };


            var point = new GLatLng(28.43039, -81.47186);
            map.addOverlay(new GMarker(point, markerOptions));

            point = new GLatLng(28.36906, -81.56063);
            map.addOverlay(new GMarker(point, markerOptions));
        }
    }

</script>
```

The values are hardcoded into the javascript right now for testing, but I need to get the dynamic values from the code-behind. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

One quick and dirty approach could be to create a string in your code-behind that creates a JavaScript array of lat/long values. You could then add an  in your .ASPX and set it to your string value. Or create a JSON representation of your points. It works well for small one-off scenarios. So your JavaScript might wind up looking like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function initialize() {
        if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
            var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
            <asp:Literal id="litMapCenter" runat="server"/>
            //map.setUIToDefault();

            var blueIcon = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);
            blueIcon.image = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png";
            markerOptions = { icon: blueIcon };

            <asp:Literal id="litMapPoints" runat="server"/>
        }
    }

</script>
```

In your code-behind you then set litMapPoints and litMapCenter with the appropriate JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this in your code behind

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.getType(), "whateveryourkeyis", string.Format("longitude={0};", pointArray[0].longitude), true);
```

This way you will simply create a jscript variable called 'longitude' and initialize it with your .NET code values.

(This is written on the fly so forgive me if there are bugs in there :-))